# Mostrar datos en una fila de una tabla si 2 datos coinciden

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un registro de ingreso y salida de cada trabajador (cada uno posee un ID) donde cada uno de ellos solo ingresa su codigo de usuario y registra sus horarios, pero sucede que algunas veces se olvidan.
Como puedo Mostrar los datos en una misma fila de una tabla (COMO SE VE EN LA IMAGEN) según la fecha del registro?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la estructura de las 4 tablas (ingreso labor, salida labor, ingreso almuerzo, salida almuerzo), los campos que necesito mostrar son la fecha y hora.
Me explico, si necesito obtener el reporte de horarios de un trabajador, pues lo filtro por su DNI y así obtengo la fechas y horas de los diferentes días que se registró, pero que pasa si olvido registrar su ingreso o su salida un dia, obviamente no van a haber datos en esos campos, como podría hacer para mostrar la información?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como pienso mostrar la información en la tabla html, en una fila muestra el dni del usuario, la fecha del registro, y las horas de ingreso,salida de su labor y refrigerio, pero si se olvido registrar un horario entonces la celda correspondiente debería quedar en blanco (en la imagen lo representa el rojo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me queda claro exactamente lo que necesitas, cual es la estructura de la tabla que quieres mostrar?

Comment: tengo 4 tablas, cada tabla tiene estos campos: id, id usuario, fecha, hora, y quiero mostrar un registro como el que se aprecia en la imagen

Comment: muestra la estructura de las trablas, ahi podremos saber como unirlas, si las tablas son iguales, creeria que lo mejor es normalizarla y tenerlas en una sola y respecto a lo que quieres seria un consulta sencilla en el que traes toda la info dependiendo del where que en este caso es la fecha y si es si olvido registrar, pone no registro a esa casilla

Comment: @srJJ ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: @JairB. sigo sin entender para que 4 tablas que guardan el mismo tipo de informacion?, realmente se requiere?, yo lo que veo, lo haria en una sola tabla y quearia mucho mas facil la consulta, pero tieniendo en cuenta que lo pones en 4 tablas diferentes, seri con joins, dejame te pongo una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que las tablas se llamen de esta manera. ingresoLabor, salidaLabor, ingresoAlmuerso y salidaAlmuerzo hacemos una consulta en la cual treaera todos los registro asociados y en caso de que el campo sea nulo pondra por defecto que 'No Resgistro' y asi quedaria el `SQL`

```
$sql="SELECT ingresoLabor.fecha, IFNULL(ingresoLabor.hora, 'No resgistro'), salidaLabor.fecha, IFNULL(salidaLabor.hora, 'No resgistro'), ingresoAlmuerso.fecha, IFNULL(ingresoAlmuerso.hora, 'No resgistro'), salidaAlmuerzo.fecha, IFNULL(salidaAlmuerzo.hora, 'No resgistro')
FROM ingresoLabor 
  INNER JOIN salidaLabor ON ingresoLabor.user_dni = salidaLabor.user_dni
  INNER JOIN ingresoAlmuerso ON ingresoLabor.user_dni = ingresoAlmuerso.user_dni 
  INNER JOIN salidaAlmuerzo  ON ingresoLabor.user_dni = salidaAlmuerzo.user_dni
WHERE ingresoLabor.fecha = '2018-09-24' AND ingresoLabor.user_dni = 71454870";
```

> Aunque por cuestiones de agilidad te recomiendo y si no estas obligado
>   a usar las 4 tablas hacerlo en una sola tabla que contenga los campos
>   que necesitas, algo asi:

```
Tabla_Registro:

id
user_dni
personal
fecha
hora_ini_lab
hora_fin_lab
hora_ini_alm
hora_fin_alm
```

asi con esto campo la consulta seria mucho mas facil, notese que omiti el campo mes, ya que con el campo fecha puedes obtener el mes, la consulta quedaria asi:

```
$sql="SELECT user_dni AS Usuario DNI, fecha AS Fecha, IFNULL(hora_ini_lab, 'No resgistro') AS 'Inicio Labor', IFNULL(hora_fin_lab, 'No resgistro') AS 'Fin Labor',  IFNULL(hora_ini_alm, 'No resgistro') AS 'Inicio Almuerzo', IFNULL(hora_fin_alm, 'No resgistro') AS 'Fin Almuerzo'
FROM Tabla_Registro 
WHERE ingresoLabor.fecha = '2018-09-24' AND ingresoLabor.user_dni = 71454870";
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue...

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que hacer un arreglo para cada vez que haces un `echo` de la información, coger la fecha y por cada día entre la anterior y la nueva que falte (con un for), crear las casillas que te faltan.

No sé si es lo optimo, pero es la única manera que se me ocurre. A no ser de que prepares algo para que todos los días mínimo se guarde una vez el registro del día.

```
<?php
$fechaAntigua = "";
foreach ($datos as $valor) {

  $fecha = $valor->fechaBBDD;//Recuperamos la fecha que nos viene

  $comprobraFecha = $fecha.explde("/", $fecha); //Creamos array separado por "/".
  $comprobraFechaAntigua = $fecha.explde("/", $fechaAntigua); //Creamos array separado por "/".

  if($comprobraFecha[0] != ($comprobraFechaAntigua[0] + 1)){ //Comparamos el día

     //En el caso de que el día no sea el siguiente a la que hemos imprimido
     for($x=($comprobraFechaAntigua[0] + 1); $x < $comprobraFecha[0]; $x++){

        //Recorremos los días faltantes y los imprimimos en la tabla
        //Aquí se imprimiría la fila $echo "<tr></tr>". No lo pongo todo.

     }
  }
  //Aquí se imprimiría la fila correspondiente a lo que nos viene de la base de datos 
  //$echo "<tr></tr>". No lo pongo todo.

  $fechaAntigua = $fecha; //Aquí se guarda la anterior para poder comparar.
}

?>
```

Esto sería un ejemplo aunque le faltan algunas comprobaciones ya que no quería ser muy extenso.

Comment: me podrías dar una idea para entenderlo mejor, por favor.

Comment: Que tal algo así? Te puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tus tablas son: ing_lab, sal_lab, ing_alm y sal_alm,  la solucion que te propongo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT ing_lab.fecha, ing_lab.hora, sal_lab.fecha, sal_lab.hora, ing_alm.fecha, ing_alm.hora, sal_alm.feche, sal_alm.hora
FROM ing_lab INNER JOIN sal_lab ON ing_lab.user_dni=sal_lab.user_dni
INNER JOIN ing_alm ON ing_lab.user_dni = ing_alm.user_dni 
INNER JOIN sal_alm  ON ing_lab.user_dni = sal_alm.user_dni;
```

de esta forma muestras solamente las fechas y las horas de cada tabla, quizas necesites mostrar el dni del usuario en cuestion, entonces debes incluir en el SELECT el user_dni para que tambien se muestre.

Comment: una vez que realice el inner join entre las 4 tablas como podria imprimirlo en una tabla, porque como decía en la descripcion, algunas veces los usuarios no registran sus horarios, ya sea de entrada, salida o almuerzo, como imprimo el resultado de la consulta en una sola fila si un campo no contiene datos. en la descripción coloco otra imagen.

Comment: Como estas haciendo un INNER JOIN por el dni del usuario, debe quedarte la tabla como mismo la nesecitas, los campos que no tienen valor se quedaran como NULL. Como consejo personal quizás haya una mejor forma de representar lo que necesitas, quizás puedes crear una sola tabla con todos los horarios, como mismo la necesitas imprimir.